# Armature not parenting to mesh

Tags: rigging, armature

I'm trying to rig an armature to a mesh but it's not moving with it in pose mode. I followed the official blender tutorial with no luck. I'm new at Blender, so I'm sure I'm missing something.

Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2pTkW-1JkE&ab_channel=Blender

File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1axgUOdGVc2sre81eudhAcSmzFt1uuwI5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parent the mesh to the armature, not the opposite, so first deparent the armature (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Clear and Keep Transformation*). Also, your mesh is a bit too dense so you need to scale both the armature and mesh (like X 3), parent the mesh to the armature *With Automatic Weights*, then scale down (/3).